# Access VBA AddNew Record Stops Working

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a button in a continuous subform that adds a certain number of identical numbers to a table. The problem I am having is with the form updating to show these records. The update works if I copy everything to a blank database. Then, the update **suddenly stops working until I hit the Refresh button (Access 2007) after about 5 seconds**.

This code is in the on click event of a button that is beside each record in the subform.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim loopYears As Integer

Set db = OpenDatabase("FILENAME.mdb")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TABLENAME",dbOpenDynaset)
loopYears = CALC TO FIND # OF YEARS

Do While loopYears > 0
    With rs
        .AddNew
        ....SET FIELDS....
        .Update
        .Bookmark = .LastModified
    End With
loopYears = loopYears - 1
Loop
Form.Requery
rs.Close
db.Close
```

I should also note there is another duplicate event like this in another subform, using another table. I mention this because I suspect somehow this connection isn't being closed properly, due to the fact that it will work the first couple times. I'm not certain if it is due to closing Access or closing the form that breaks the code.

Comment: I doubt if it's the source of your problem--the code is probably correct in your actual db--but as posted, that loop will be infinite (until overflow). I think you meant `loopYears = loopYears - 1`

Comment: @RolandTumble You are right, I've edited it to show that.

Comment: Maybe the form's RecordSource should be set to nothing while this is going on?

Comment: This code is in the click event of a button in a continuous subform -- I'll try the suggestion to set to nothing before closing the form on Monday. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Why are you doing this? You don't give the details of what "....SET FIELDS...." entails, but looping like this is very often completely unnecessary -- it can very often be replaced with a SQL statement that updates all records as a batch. Also, if you're opening a recordset on the table you're displaying in the form, that's also a mistake. If you insist on looping then loop through the form's Recordset -- changes will be shown immediately, I think (or, at least, within the default 1-second refresh interval).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, David. I'm learning mostly by editing code samples and this is one example of there being a lot of examples of code that work, but aren't the best way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

most people use an INSERT statement to do this, instead of opening a recordset and then adding a record.

I know if it was erroring out on me, that's the first thing I'd try is to change it to a SQL INSERT statment.